# What do you mean by kernel

Tags: kernel

I have many times come across this word. I even know a little about it but don't know exactly what it is.

Answer (score 4):

Visit the wiki pages of [Kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) and [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) for information.

In simple terms, the kernel is a key component of operating systems, which mediates between software and the hardware. When an application needs the hardware to do something (this is known as a system call), it sends a request to the kernel, which in turn interprets the command for the hardware.

[image]

Both the hardware and the software communicate both ways with the kernel.

In the context of Android, the kernel is not user-accessible without superuser permissions. Thus, many users flash a custom kernel, to tweak hardware settings such as CPU clock speed and File System Architectures.

For further reading, look [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-z-what-kernel) and [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/android-basics-101-understanding-kernels-xda-developer-tv/).